# How to improve heap utilization to prevent/delay GC?

Tags: jvm, garbage-collection

I have allocated 8G initial heap size to a java application (which generates a lot of one-time-use objects) and have ran it for 12 hours approximately and I have a cronjob to kill the java process after 22 hours have passed. Looking at the heap information from successive thread dumps:

```
Heap
 garbage-first heap   total 8388608K, used 526854K [0x00000003d5a00000, 0x00000003d5c08000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 259 young (530432K), 6 survivors (12288K)
 Metaspace       used 22982K, capacity 44820K, committed 44928K, reserved 1114112K
  class space    used 2666K, capacity 2862K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K

Heap
 garbage-first heap   total 8388608K, used 758278K [0x00000003d5a00000, 0x00000003d5c08000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 372 young (761856K), 6 survivors (12288K)
 Metaspace       used 22982K, capacity 44820K, committed 44928K, reserved 1114112K
  class space    used 2666K, capacity 2862K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K
```

It seems that the heap is very underutilized. 8G allocated, but used is only about 0.7G approximately.

However, when looking at the gc logs, I noted that there are 3 young gc.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.352-b08) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_352-b08), built on Oct 17 2022 20:39:31 by "mockbuild" with gcc 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-10)
Memory: 4k page, physical 65685332k(28882716k free), swap 4194300k(4194300k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-DisableExplicitGC -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=2097152 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=60 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:InitialBootClassLoaderMetaspaceSize=33554432 -XX:InitialHeapSize=8589934592 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:MaxHeapSize=16815444992 -XX:MetaspaceSize=104857600 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC
2023-03-28T10:27:28.325+0800: 2591.299: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 1638M->12571K(8192M), 0.0492549 secs]
2023-03-28T11:27:05.000+0800: 6167.975: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 1636M->9215K(8192M), 0.0406190 secs]
2023-03-28T13:38:51.005+0800: 14073.980: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 1636M->10758K(8192M), 0.0292244 secs]
```

edit: just checked the oracle technical articles [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/g1gc.html) it does say to avoid fixing young generation size with NewRatio or Xmn. I suppose it suggests the use of -XX:G1NewSizePercent?

edit:
Given that it is underutilized, can I increase my young generation size <strike>-XX:NewSize=size</strike> `-XX:G1NewSizePercent` to higher values in order to prevent/delay GC pauses? It doesnt seem as if there are any allocations to the old generation (though I find it weird, since I do use an object pool to reuse container objects - so the object pool and its elements should be "old"?).

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59995813/16034206) which suggests not to touch the sizing for young generation and allow G1GC to handle it on its own. So I m not too sure whether to proceed with the above.

Comment: What’s stopping you from trying the suggestion “not to touch the sizing for young generation”? That’s as easy as removing all those options. Why did you even think you have to specify these options, in other words, that you were smarter than the JVM developers who defined the defaults?

Comment: I dont think I am, but I m told by senior developers that for a "simple" application such as the one I am using right now, it should have as minimal/zero GC, and that I should tune it until it doesnt.

Comment: Well, there’s [Epsilon GC](https://openjdk.org/jeps/318) which doesn’t collect any garbage. You can try it and if your application aborts due to being out of memory, the senior developer was wrong about this application not needing any garbage collection. If garbage collection is needed, there is no difference to any other application. With G1GC, specify your pause time goal and nothing else and see how it turns out. Any other option requires a deeper understanding of the implementation and especially simple applications do not need such effort.

Comment: given that I m trying to read then persist market data, will 1 millisecond pause time goals be better than trying to delay/prevent the gc as much as possible until i can finally kill the application using the cronjob?

Comment: So you actually have a cronjob with no latency requirement? Then, pause times do not matter and to get maximum throughput, don’t use a concurrent GC at all. Use SerialGC or ParallelGC. They already have the property of only starting when the heap is (almost) full.

Comment: Really? “read then persist market data” doesn’t sound like a task with latency requirements. No, a GC pause does not imply packet loss. The TCP/IP stack has a buffer and you can increment it for a connection if really necessary, but I doubt that you will need it. I remember you said that your senior developer called it a “simple” application…

Comment: I see! I really appreciate you taking your time to answer. I ll do my best to revise it accordingly. yes, it is simple. it listens to market data on udp then persists it. it doesnt do any sort of special checking or processing of the data, though the persisting part could be considered processing.